# Ruby Google API key and analytics

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, google-analytics

I am creating a Ruby application that needs to access dozens (maybe hundreds) of different Google Analytics accounts, query each account, and then generate a report based on the results. I know I can achieve this using Googles API client ( http://code.google.com/p/google-api-ruby-client/ ) and Oauth, but that would require manually generating a set of keys and credentials for each analytics account which is not really feasible. I'm wondering if there is another way to access google analytics (perhaps using the API Keys?) that bypasses the need to generate credentials manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After quite a bit of tinkering, I've finally stumbled upon a solution to my particular problem. As it turns out, I don't need to create a separate Developer account for each Analytics account I want to access. I can simply create a single Developer account, and then add that Developer accounts' email address to the set of users that are able to access the Analytics account. This will allow me to access multiple Analytics accounts using the same Developer account.

Yes, it will still require quite a bit of work adding the Developer email account to hundreds of Google Analytics accounts, but it pales in comparison to creating a separate set of Developer credentials for each Analytics account.